# Joomla mysql query isnt working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

I have the following code:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query = "UPDATE #__cspartners_partners SET estado = '".TpoEstadoDocumentacion::Revisar."'  WHERE id='" .$id. "'";
$db->setQuery($query);              
$resultado = $db->query();
if(!$resultado) return 0;
```

`$query` returns this:

```
string(60) "UPDATE #__cspartners_partners SET estado = '3' WHERE id='1'"
```

And `$resultado` returns this:

```
bool(true)
```

If I execute this query directly in phpMyAdmin it works fine but its not working in my code. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the Documentation for writing database queries so that you are aware of the latest coding standards.

For the query use this:

```
$value = TpoEstadoDocumentacion::Revisar; 

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$fields = array(
    $db->quoteName('estado') . ' = ' . $db->quote($value)
);   
$conditions = array(
    $db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . (int)$id
);   
$query->update($db->quoteName('#__cspartners_partners'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);  
$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->execute();
```